# SQL: Create Home & Away query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two queries that produce the following:

```
mysql>  select f.fixturematchday, f.fixtureid, t.teamname as homeTeam
          from straightred_fixture as f,
               straightred_team as t
          where f.fixturematchday = 15 and f.hometeamid = t.teamid;

+-----------------+-----------+-------------+
| fixturematchday | fixtureid | homeTeam    |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+
|              15 |    364393 | Hull        |
|              15 |    364394 | Leicester   |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select f.fixturematchday, f.fixtureid, t.teamname as awayTeam 
         from straightred_fixture as f,
              straightred_team as t 
         where f.fixturematchday = 15 and f.awayteamid = t.teamid;
+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| fixturematchday | fixtureid | awayTeam       |
+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
|              15 |    364393 | Crystal Palace |
|              15 |    364394 | Man City       |
+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I would like to return:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| fixturematchday | fixtureid | homeTeam    | awayTeam       |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
|              15 |    364393 | Hull        | Crystal Palace |
|              15 |    364394 | Leicester   | Man City       |
+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
```

I am assuming some sort of join is required.

Comment: What is your first query, the `homeTeam` one?

Comment: Yes it is.  Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I was asking for you to ***provide*** the 1st query.  You show two result sets, but only one query.  If you provide *both* queries, it would be easier to `JOIN` them to get your result.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to show sample contents from your tables too.

Comment: P.S. By listing multiple tables in your `FROM` and by adding `f.awayteamid = t.teamid` in your `WHERE`, you are *already* doing an (`INNER`) `JOIN`.

Comment: sorry, first query added.  Perhaps I should goto bed lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *already* doing a `JOIN` in these queries.  You are joining `straightred_team` in order to get the team name.  What you can do is `JOIN` that table *twice*, once for `f.hometeamid` and once for `f.awayteamid`.

<sub>Note: It's totally fine to JOIN the same table multiple times, it's also fine to JOIN a table to itself.</sub>

```
select f.fixturematchday, f.fixtureid,
       th.teamname as homeTeam, ta.teamname as awayTeam
from straightred_fixture as f,
     straightred_team as th,
     straightred_team as ta
where f.fixturematchday = 15
  and f.hometeamid = th.teamid
  and f.awayteamid = ta.teamid;
```

You can also write this query using the `JOIN .. ON` syntax instead:

```
SELECT f.fixturematchday, f.fixtureid,
       th.teamname as homeTeam, ta.teamname as awayTeam
FROM straightred_fixture as f
JOIN straightred_team as th ON f.hometeamid = th.teamid
JOIN straightred_team as ta ON f.awayteamid = ta.teamid
WHERE f.fixturematchday = 15
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.fixturematchday, a.fixtureid, 
    (SELECT teamName FROM straightred_team t WHERE t.teamid = a.hometeamid) 
    AS homeTeam, 
    (SELECT teamName FROM straightred_team t WHERE t.teamid = a.awayteamid) 
    AS awayteam
FROM fixturematchday AS a
WHERE a.fixturematchday = 15
```

I think two subselects should be the most easy way